# High usage and random lines appearing randomly when playing games

Tags: windows-10, display, hdmi, amd-radeon, gaming

Recently I bought a new PC, everything worked very well and all. But a couple of days ago, I noticed that when I was playing games, random black or white lines would appear on anything that was moving on the screen.
I don't have this problem when I'm using Firefox or watching videos, just when I'm playing games.

These are the general specs of my PC :

[image]

Plus I have a Radeon RX 580 8GB GDDR5 graphics card, and a Thermaltake TR2 S 700W 80 Plus power supply.

This is how the task manager appears when playing games:

[image]

And this is an example of the problem I have:

[Youtube video with an example of my problem, as I can't do a screenshot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VrTwqWdBgu8&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind that might have caused your problem is graphics card driver, don't say Windows have determined "The best drivers for your device are already installed...", please don't believe that, install the driver from your OEM's site and see if it solves your problem.